# winform program not able to read data from sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

i have a sql table that is created like this

```
create table users
(username varchar(20) not null,
pass varchar(30) null,
phoneNum char(8) null,
email varchar(50) null,
name varchar(50) null,
membership varchar(3) null,
rating char(1) null,
primary key(username))
```

i also have a winform program that is trying to read data from it. i currently have this:

```
public DataTable loadUserData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Define connection object
                        conn.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;

                        //Define command object
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users";
                        cmd.Connection = conn;

                        //Define data adapter object
                        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        //Open connection
                        conn.Open();

                        //Execute command
                        userDataTable.Clear();
                        dataAdapter.Fill(userDataTable);
                    }//try
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }//using sql command
        }//using sql connection
        return userDataTable;
    }
```

and this is able to load the data(i think).Then in the other form where i need to use the data, i have something like this:

```
 DataTable dt = db.loadUserData();
 foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
     else if (txtPassword.Text == dr["pass"].ToString())
                {
                    //code to login
                }
 }
```

but i keep getting an error like this
[image]

this error only occurs when i type my password correctly. Am i doing something wrong here or why does it not work?

this is my complete foreach loop:

```
Database db = new Database(); //Database is the class where loadUserdata is found
int count = 0;
        DataTable udt = db.loadUserData();
        DataTable rdt = db.loadRoomsData();
        foreach(DataRow udr in udt.Rows)
        {
            if (txtUsername.TextLength == 0)
            {
                lblVerify.Visible = true;
                lblVerify.Text = "Please enter a username";
                txtUsername.Focus();
                break;
            }
            else if (txtUsername.Text.ToLower() == udr["username"].ToString())
            {
                if (txtPassword.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    lblVerify.Visible = true;
                    lblVerify.Text = "Please enter the password";
                    txtPassword.Focus();
                    break;
                }
                else if (txtUsername.Text.ToLower() == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "admin")
                {
                    Administrator admin = new Administrator();
                    admin.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                    break;
                }
                else if (txtPassword.Text == udr["pass"].ToString() && checkBooking() == true)
                {
                    Receipt rcpt = new Receipt(udr["username"].ToString(), backColor);
                    rcpt.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                    break;
                }
                else if (checkFull() == true)
                {
                    lblVerify.Visible = true;
                    lblVerify.Text = "All our hotels are currently fully booked. Sorry for the incovenience caused";
                    break;
                }
                else if (txtPassword.Text == udr["pass"].ToString())
                {
                    Main hotel = new Main(txtUsername.Text, backColor);
                    hotel.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblVerify.Visible = true;
                    lblVerify.Text = "Password does not match Username. Please try again";
                    txtPassword.Focus();
                    txtPassword.SelectAll();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(udr["username"].ToString() != txtUsername.Text)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

i debugged the program and the exact line where the error appeared is the

```
`else if (txtPassword.Text == dr["pass"].ToString())'
```

Comment: My teacher asked me to do that

Comment: The usings are not the problem here. not sure why the `userDataTable` is not declared inside the method, but I'm guessing this has something to do with it.

Comment: Can you share the complete code of foreach loop?

Comment: You can use debug point and see which line you are getting the error. Sharing that line will ease out to help better.

Comment: Wrapping an a `using` each IDisposable instance you create is a good practice. Now you can get rid of the `try/catch/finally` you used, since its only value is to be sure `conn` is properly closed, which will be any way since you are `using` it

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i added it

Comment: @Venkatesh how do i do that?

Comment: I hope you are using Visual Studio for your development... You can add breakpoint before the loop and from there F10 to step into each line..

Comment: @Venkatesh the line of error is the else if (txtPassword.Text == dr["pass"].ToString())

Comment: Is this line succeeds "else if (txtPassword.Text == udr["pass"].ToString() && checkBooking() == true)" ? Are you doing any data row remove in 'CheckFull()' function?

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry guys i found the error. there was a problem with my checkBooking() function and i think i know how to solve it alr. thanks everyone.